# Jquery how to close last video before streaming the next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, onclick, youtube-iframe-api

I am working on this code from the last 2 days. I tried many solutions but i am not able to achieve what i want.

this is my code

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="myLink('0HTo_ySoct4');">Click me!</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myLink('PxWDfisVmzg');">Click me!</a>

<div id="0HTo_ySoct4">The text will get loaded here</div>
<div id="PxWDfisVmzg">The text will get loaded here</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function myLink(Yt) {
var yout = Yt;
var myurl = '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + yout + '?autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=1" width="450" height="300" frameborder="0" class="player"></iframe>';

$('.player').hide();

$("#"+yout).html(myurl);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me explain what i want and what the code is doing.

See, i have 2 click me tab. i can have more click me tab around 20, well it depends on the results.

All tab contains a youtube video id.

so when i click on any click me tab to play the video. The video will get loaded in their related div. This is indeed. i want to load each video just below their particular video description / details. Its working but with a bug.

The bug is, when i tried to click on the 2nd click me tab. The first one will get hide from the webpage but the video will still play in the background and you will listen audio of both video's.

I want to completely close the previous video before playing the next one.
I did many changes but did not get it fixed so now i need little help from you expert guys.

please help me.

How can i completely close all the last videos before playing the next one ?
Just because div id is different i am having this issue but i need that in my project.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Similar to your method I like to keep the unloaded videos in source= then load them into src= when they're to be played. To stop I use attr('src', '') to clear src while source= retains the url for the next time it is played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="myLink('0HTo_ySoct4');">Click me!</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myLink('PxWDfisVmzg');">Click me!</a>

<div class="youtubeVideo" id="0HTo_ySoct4">The text will get loaded here</div>
<div class="youtubeVideo" id="PxWDfisVmzg">The text will get loaded here</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function myLink(Yt) {
var yout = Yt;
var myurl = '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + yout + '?autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=1" width="450" height="300" frameborder="0" class="player"></iframe>';

$('.player').hide();
$(".youtubeVideo").empty();
$("#"+yout).html(myurl);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

basically empty all the divs showing the video before loading the new one in its corresponding div